# Не заполняет List<Product>

Tags: java, android, list, retrofit

Здравствуйте.

Вот мой код:

```
productlist = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < idies.length; i++) {

        Call<Product> favoriteCall = restservice.getService().getFavorites(idies[0]);
        favoriteCall.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                Log.d("Product_name", response.body().getProduct_name());                   
                productlist.add(response.body());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

При этом `response` не пустой. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Еще обнаружил при дебаге response.body() показывается как null, но в лог данные выводятся

Answer (score 0):

Вроде только один раз можно прочитать ответ. Попробуйте поместить ответ в переменную и только после этого выводить что-то в логи и складировать в список. Т.е.

```
        favoriteCall.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
            Product product = response.body();
            Log.d("Product_name", product.getProduct_name());                   
            productlist.add(product);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но не сработало

Comment: @РасулA-ев, может дело в том что у вас всегда один и тот же элемент массива? `.getFavorites(idies[0])`?

Comment: Это я поменял, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @РасулA-ев, Видать ошибка где-то в другом месте. Может вы не там и не так проверяете что список не пуст или не тот список проверяете...